# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in Linux Hosting with cPanel is not working

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I have tried everything I found in different sites, but nothing is working.

These are all the differents solutions I have tried in my .htaccess file.
I have tried all the solutions one by one and also some combinations, but nothing is working.

```
RewriteEngine On

# 1 option
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# 2 option
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.camp$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.camp$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.camp/$1 [L,R=301]


# 3 option
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\\.camp [NC] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.camp/$1 [R,L]

# 4 option
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.camp [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.camp$
RewriteRule .* https://www.mywebsite.camp%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# 5 option
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]


# 6 option
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]



#### Remove index.php ###
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
#### index.php ###
```

When I try to access my website directly from the browser typing: https://mywebsite.camp/ it works perfectly

What can I do?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you using Cloudflare CDN?

Comment: No, I'm not. Why?